# Failed to cast fixed type column QUANTITY. Max fixed type precision reached

Tags: hana

My calculation view is giving this error in the union node. 
What does this mean and how can I resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to reference on [CDS data types](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/4ee2f261e9c44003807d08ccc2e249ac.html)

Probably, your Quantity column has a value which has a bigger precision than the data type you're trying to convert or cast in your CDS view

You could share the code block where CAST occurs in your CDS view
Also you can share the data type of the source of Quantity column so we can comment more confidently